# Dialogflow wrong time format

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

Basically, my agent is French, and when I type 10h (10am for 12hour format) my DialogFlow agent is understanding 22h (10PM) but I want him to understand 10AM. (I want 24 hour format).

And the strange thing is that when I type 14h, my agent is understanding 2PM.

Maybe I need to modify somewhere the time format from 12 to 24 but I can't find where.

Sorry for this poor english and explanation hope you understand.

[image: My agent]

[image: Intent]

[image: timezone]

Comment: Did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a long shot, but have you tried using the `@sys.date-time` entity instead?

According to the [Dialogflow Enterprise (FR) documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow-enterprise/docs/reference/system-entities), @sys.date-time accepts inputs like

```
14h30
13 juillet
avril
Matin
demain à 16h30
demain dans l'après-midi
```

and returns objects like

```
"2018-04-05T14:30:00-06:00"
"2018-07-13T18:00:00-06:00"
{"startDate":"2018-04-01T12:00:00-06:00","endDate":"2018-04-30T12:00:00-06:00"}
{"startTime":"2018-04-06T08:00:00-06:00","endTime":"2018-04-06T12:00:00-06:00"}
{"date_time":"2018-04-06T16:30:00-06:00"}
{"startDateTime":"2018-04-06T12:00:00-06:00","endDateTime":"2018-04-06T16:00:00-06:00"}
```

Comment: Just tried, not working :/  When I type 10h30 DialogFlow parses it like 22h30 and returns "2019-04-29T22:30:00+02:00"

Answer (score 0):

I tried

```
function getLocaleTimeString(dateObj){
  return dateObj.toLocaleTimeString('pt-BR', { hour: 'numeric', hour12: false });
}
```

and didn't worked :-(